# Node.js unittest Stubbing Own function

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, tdd, sinon

Apologies if this was asked before. Here is the module that I'd like to unittest inside file `getStuff.js`. I'm having difficulty stubbing the`resolveThing` module used here.

`getStuff.js`

```
const resolveThing = require('./resolveThing.js');

module.exports = async function getStuff(target, stuff) {
  const { element, test, other } = resolveThing(target);

  try {
    return element;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error('Did not work.');
  }
};
```

And here is my attempt at the unittest with stubbing using sinon. However when I try to run this it errors out with `TypeError: Cannot stub non-existent own property resolveType`. Anyone know how I can get this test to work?

```
const getStuff = require('../com/getStuff');
const resolveThing = require('../com/resolveThing');

const mochaccino = require('mochaccino');

const { expect } = mochaccino;
const sinon = require('sinon');


describe('com.resolveThing', function() {
    beforeEach(function () {
        sinon.stub(resolveThing, 'resolveThing').returns({element:'a',test:'b',other:'c'});
    });

    afterEach(function () {
        resolveThing.restore();
    });

    it('Standard message', function() {
        const answer = getAttribute('a','b');
        expect(answer).toEqual('a');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sinon.stub(resolveThing, 'resolveThing').returns({element:'a',test:'b',other:'c'});
```

`resolveThing` must be an object and `'resolveThing'` must be a function in the object, an exception is thrown if the property is not already a function.

I think this is what's hapning in your case.

Comment: Yes, I suspect that is the case. Do you know how I can modify my test or function for it to work?

Comment: maybe you can create an object where you put your function like this:
const resolveThingObject = {resolveThingFn : resolveThing}, and then use your new object:
sinon.stub(resolveThingObject,'resolveThingFn').returns({element:'a',test:'b',other:'c'});